# XDocument Saving Error in Mono "This XmlWriter does not accept Text at this state Prolog."

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement, xmlwriter

I am trying to save an xml document, and I have been trying to get my code to work but mono is spitting out a very strange error. I have given the file it is trying to save to full ownership.

An example would be group.test.test to "Hello world!"

Here is the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Classic6
{
public class XmlSettings
{
    private Dictionary<string, XmlSetting> Values { get; set; }
    private string[] SettingFiles;
    public bool EnableSaving { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<SettingChangedEventArgs> OnSettingChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// The location of the XML file that new keys
    /// should be stored in (when a key is added
    /// via XmlSettings["key"] without a file, it
    /// will be saved here.
    /// </summary>
    public static string DefaultFile { get; set; }

    public XmlSettings()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<string, XmlSetting>();
        EnableSaving = false;
    }

    public void Load(string SettingsDirectory)
    {
        SettingFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SettingsDirectory, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in SettingFiles)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream s = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
                XDocument d = XDocument.Load(s);
                s.Close();
                LoadRecursive(d.Root, file, string.Empty);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultFile))
            DefaultFile = Path.Combine(SettingsDirectory, "bla.xml.bak.invalid");
    }

    private void LoadRecursive(XElement root, string sourceFile, string path)
    {
        foreach (XElement e in root.Elements())
        {
            if (e.Elements().Count() != 0)
                LoadRecursive(e, sourceFile, path + e.Name + ".");
            foreach (XAttribute a in e.Attributes())
            {
                Values[(path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString() + "." +
                    a.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower()] = new XmlSetting(sourceFile, a.Value, true);
            }
            if (Values.ContainsKey((path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower()))
            {
                if (Values[(path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower()].Value != e.Value)
                {
                    if (OnSettingChanged != null)
                        OnSettingChanged(this, new SettingChangedEventArgs((path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower(),
                            Values[(path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower()].Value, e.Value));
                }
            }
            Values[(path + e.Name.LocalName.ToString()).ToLower()] = new XmlSetting(sourceFile, e.Value, false);
        }
    }

    public int GetInt(string Key)
    {
        int i = -1;
        if (!int.TryParse(this[Key], out i) && !Key.StartsWith("command") && !Key.Contains("port"))
            Server.server.Log("Setting error: " + Key + " is not a valid integer.");
        return i;
    }

    public bool GetBool(string Key)
    {
        bool b = false;
        if (!bool.TryParse(this[Key], out b))
            Server.server.Log("Setting error: " + Key + " is not a valid boolean.");
        return b;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string Key)
    {
        return Values.ContainsKey(Key.ToLower());
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Values.ContainsKey(key.ToLower()))
                return "";
            return Values[key.ToLower()].Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (OnSettingChanged != null)
                OnSettingChanged(this, new SettingChangedEventArgs(key, Values.ContainsKey(key.ToLower()) ? Values[key.ToLower()].Value : DefaultFile, value));
            if (Values.ContainsKey(key))
                Values[key.ToLower()].Value = value;
            else
                Values[key.ToLower()] = new XmlSetting(DefaultFile, value, false);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultFile))
                return;
            if (!EnableSaving)
                return;

            XDocument d = new XDocument();

            if (File.Exists(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile))
            {
                Stream s = File.Open(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                d = XDocument.Load(s, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
                s.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                d = new XDocument();
                d.Add(new XElement("Classic6"));
            }
            // Locate this property
            string[] parts = key.ToLower().Split('.');
            XElement currentElement = d.Root;
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++ )
            {
                bool found = false;
                if (parts.Length - 1 == i)
                {
                    foreach (XAttribute a in currentElement.Attributes())
                    {
                        if (a.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == parts[i])
                        {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (XElement e in currentElement.Elements())
                {
                    if (e.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == parts[i])
                    {
                        currentElement = e;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    XElement el = new XElement(parts[i]);
                    currentElement.Add(el);
                    currentElement = el;
                }
            }
            if (Values[key.ToLower()].IsAttribute)
                currentElement.SetAttributeValue(parts[parts.Length - 1], Values[key.ToLower()].Value);
            else
                currentElement.SetValue(Values[key.ToLower()].Value);

            d.Save(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile);
        }
    }
}

internal class XmlSetting
{
    public string SourceFile { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsAttribute { get; set; }

    public XmlSetting(string SourceFile, string Value, bool IsAttribute)
    {
        this.SourceFile = SourceFile;
        this.Value = Value;
        this.IsAttribute = IsAttribute;
    }
}

public class SettingChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string OldValue { get; set; }
    public string NewValue { get; set; }

    public SettingChangedEventArgs(string Key, string OldValue, string NewValue)
    {
        this.Key = Key;
        this.OldValue = OldValue;
        this.NewValue = NewValue;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the error it gives me:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This XmlWriter does not accept Text at this state Prolog.
at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.ShiftStateContent (System.String occured, Boolean allowAttribute) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteString (System.String text) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.DefaultXmlWriter.WriteString (System.String text) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XText.WriteTo (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.String filename, SaveOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.XmlSettings.set_Item (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.CmdSettings.Use (Classic6.RemoteClient c, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.ClassicServer.HandleCommand (Classic6.RemoteClient c, System.String msg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6Server.Program.ParseInput (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6Server.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: This XmlWriter does not accept Text at this state Prolog.
at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.ShiftStateContent (System.String occured, Boolean allowAttribute) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteString (System.String text) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.DefaultXmlWriter.WriteString (System.String text) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XText.WriteTo (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.Xml.XmlWriter w) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.String filename, SaveOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save (System.String filename) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.XmlSettings.set_Item (System.String key, System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.CmdSettings.Use (Classic6.RemoteClient c, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6.ClassicServer.HandleCommand (Classic6.RemoteClient c, System.String msg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6Server.Program.ParseInput (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Classic6Server.Program.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and in the xml file it overwrites it completely and only leaves this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

which is a lot different from this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Classic6>
  <group>
   <test>Will I change</test>
   <well>I hope so</well>
  </group>
</Classic6>
```

Comment: How do you call this code? And couldn't you post only the relevant bits of the code?

Comment: Sorry.. I'm new at this. The error is called at

`"d.Save(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile);"`

and I call this code by 

`"Server.Settings["group.test.test"] = "Hello world!";`

Comment: +1 for svick. Yeah, paring this down to the minimal code that causes the problem would be *extremely* helpful. This problem can be reproduced in 1 or 2 lines of code, as listed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157642/mono-xdocument-load-fails-with-loadoptions-preservewhitespace). Cheers and happing coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We figured it out: Mono doesn't play well with whitespace, apparently, so doing this:

```
            d = XDocument.Load(s, LoadOptions.None);
```

instead of this

```
            d = XDocument.Load(s, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

will let it save properly.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm writing a build script to modify an Info.plist file for MonoTouch to automatically update the version number from my Jenkins build. Since the file is stored in git, I'd much rather keep the whitespace in tact.

Comment: See [mono-xdocument-load-fails-with-loadoptions-preservewhitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157642/mono-xdocument-load-fails-with-loadoptions-preservewhitespace) for an easy workaround if you want to preserve whitespace: `doc.Root.Save("out.xml")`

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the encodings of the files you read and how it is written it might be  byte order mark that makes the xmlwriter go nuts

Comment: It is UTF-8 and doesn't have a BOM (I checked through hex), I am using linux.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find out an another workaround while preserving whitespaces. It is evident that Mono fails to save XDocument that was opened using *LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace*. It seems to be a bug in Mono runtime implementation. Because, I didn't encounter any issues in MS CLR implementation on Windows platform.

The workaround is as below: (Here, you can still using *LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace* in XDocument.Load method)

```
d.Root.Save(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile);
```

Instead of using

```
d.Save(Values[key.ToLower()].SourceFile);
```

It works well for me using Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.5 on Ubuntu 11.10 platform.